# "git checkout -- filename" vs "git checkout filename"

Tags: ubuntu, git

I know that I am meant to use `git checkout -- filename` to revert the changes made to a specific file. But one of my colleague just ignore the dashes and ended typing `git checkout filename`, effectively resulting in the same action.

Is this something git specific or am I just ignorant of an underlying mechanism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

```
git checkout [-f|--ours|--theirs|-m|--conflict=<style>] [<tree-ish>] [--] <paths>…​
```

The `--` is used to separate the paths from the options.  You need this since some of the options have optional parameters, so if you didn't include the `--` the command may try to interpret a path as an option parameter.  As you can see from the docs, the `--` is optional when it is not actually required to separate options from paths.